# Angular 6 how can I manually add style scope attributes to style string from variable?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

I want to find a way to get these attribute names for in component.ts file: `_ngcontent` and `_nghost`

And use it to add a scope for styles from a variable.

component.ts

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input() styles: string
    styleNode

    ngOnInit() {
        this._updateStyles()
    }

    ngOnChanges() {
        this._updateStyles()
    }

    private _updateStyles() {
        if (this.styles && this.styles.length) {
            if (!this.styleNode) {
                this._addCustomStyleNode()
            }
            // <---- I want to add ngcontent attributes to this.styles string here
            this._updateStyleNodeContent()
        }
    }

    private _addCustomStyleNode() {
        this.styleNode = document.createElement('style')
        this.styleNode.type = 'text/css'
        const head = document.querySelector('head')
        head.appendChild(this.styleNode)
    }

    private _updateStyleNodeContent() {
        while (this.styleNode.firstChild) {
            this.styleNode.removeChild(this.styleNode.firstChild)
        }
        this.styleNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.styles))
    }

}
```

Does anybody know how to get these metadata?
Or maybe there is some way how can I populate my styles variable with this `ngcontent` attributes out of the Angular box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_nghost-xxx` and `_ngcontent-xxx` will have the same `xxx` number for a component. The component itself will have the `_nghost` attribute applied and the content in your template will get the `_ngcontent` attribute applied. You can get a reference to your component's element and find the `_nghost` attribute on that. Here is one quick example of doing that:

```js
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  this.ngHost = Object.keys(this.elementRef.nativeElement.attributes)
    .map(k => this.elementRef.nativeElement.attributes[k].name)
    .find(k => k.includes('_nghost'));
  this.ngContent = this.ngHost.replace('nghost', 'ngcontent');
}
```